# How to webscrape deeply nested XML?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape XML data into Google Sheets using the `importxml` function. I previously tried using the importhtml function, but the "list" and "table" query you need to use doesn't work.

I can't seem to work out the correct way to scrape the "Price (GBX)" value in a simple Market Data webpage, such as https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/summary?s=LSE:LSE

I have tried to use search by div, span and class name but am not getting anywhere.

I have also tried to copy the XPath `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/span[2]`
but this doesn't seem to work

Is it possible to retrieve data that is very nested through XML scraping in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//ul/li/span[@class='mod-ui-data-list__label'][contains(text(),'GBX')]/following-sibling::span")
```

Output:

> 7576.00